# CollectionVIewCell Text Rendering Issues

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So I have a comments feature in my app that users use to communicate. Each comment has a pic, some text,a button that lets you either flag or reply to comments, and the how long ago the comment was posted. As seen in the picture below

[image]

However as seen in the picture there is a clear problem. Depending on the amount of text typically anything that spans one line or more. The time label does not show.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

protocol CommentCellDelegate: class {
    func optionsButtonTapped(cell: CommentCell)
    func handleProfileTransition(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer)
}
class CommentCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    weak var delegate: CommentCellDelegate? = nil
    override var reuseIdentifier : String {
        get {
            return "cellID"
        }
        set {
            // nothing, because only red is allowed
        }
    }
    var didTapOptionsButtonForCell: ((CommentCell) -> Void)?

    weak var comment: CommentGrabbed?{
        didSet{
            guard let comment = comment else{
                return
            }
          //  print("apples")
            // textLabel.text = comment.content
            //shawn was also here
            profileImageView.loadImage(urlString: comment.user.profilePic!)
            //  print(comment.user.username)
            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: comment.user.username!, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)])

            attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: " " + (comment.content), attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]))

            attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n\n", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 4)]))
            let timeAgoDisplay = comment.creationDate.timeAgoDisplay()
            attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: timeAgoDisplay, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]))

            textView.attributedText = attributedText


        }
    }

    lazy var textView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 2
        textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
        textView.isEditable = false
        return textView
    }()

    lazy var profileImageView: CustomImageView = {
        let iv = CustomImageView()
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        iv.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleProfileTransition)))
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return iv
    }()

    lazy var flagButton: UIButton = {
        let flagButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        flagButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icons8-Info-64"), for: .normal)
        flagButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(optionsButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return flagButton
    }()

    @objc func optionsButtonTapped (){
        didTapOptionsButtonForCell?(self)
    }

    @objc func onOptionsTapped() {
        delegate?.optionsButtonTapped(cell: self)
    }
    @objc func handleProfileTransition(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        delegate?.handleProfileTransition(tapGesture: tapGesture)
      //  print("Tapped image")
    }



    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(textView)
        addSubview(profileImageView)
        addSubview(flagButton)
        textView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: profileImageView.rightAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: flagButton.leftAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 4, paddingBottom: 4, paddingRight: 4, width: 0, height: 0)
        profileImageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 40/2
        flagButton.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 4, width: 40, height: 40)
        flagButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CommentCell.onOptionsTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I figured it was my constraints but it doesn't seem like it is. Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Comment: You have to implement Autosizing feature : [Tutorial](https://medium.com/@wasinwiwongsak/uicollectionview-with-autosizing-cell-using-autolayout-in-ios-9-10-84ab5cdf35a2)

Comment: yea but the cell seems to already adjust based off the amount of text, does that not count?

Comment: set `maximumNumberOfLines ` to zero.

Comment: You should also add the subviews to contentView

Comment: im going to try that give me a second

Comment: @LalKrishna i wish you would've put that as an answer I would've gave you credit for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autosizing works only when `maximumNumberOfLines` is zero.

```
textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0
```

Refer: [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextcontainer/1444531-maximumnumberoflines)